Customize font style for large navigation bar title in SwiftUI
I am using the large navigation bar title in a SwiftUI view. How can I set a .serif and .black font style for the navigation bar tile?
Unfortunately I cannot modify attributes when setting the navigationBarTitle
`


See Change NavigationStack title font, tint, and background in SwiftUI

The one way I know is to change the appearance of NavigationBar in the whole app.
You can do this by calling this code:
let largeTitle = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .extraLargeTitle)
let regularTitle = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)

 // Define descriptor with rounded design
let descriptor = largeTitle.fontDescriptor.withDesign(.rounded)!
let largeFont = UIFont(descriptor: descriptor, size: largeTitle.pointSize)
let regularFont = UIFont(descriptor: descriptor, size: regularTitle.pointSize)

// For large title
UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [.font : largeFont]

// For inline title
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [.font : regularFont]

The important part here is to instantiate a font descriptor which you can setup whatever you like.
Though, right how I mentioned at the beginning this will change navigation bar appearance in the whole app.



Serif
Rounded














Even on iOS 18 it is only possible solution to change the font. Maybe one day Apple gonna allow us to use modifiers on navigation bar title.

You will probably encounter an issue after that where AccentColor is overridden to the default blue color (iOS 18). Here’s how to fix it:
Add this line:
.accentColor(.red)

like this:
@main
struct YourApp: App {
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .accentColor(.red)
        }
    }
}


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
